# Which one? Agilo+Trac+SVN or Redmine+RedmineBacklogs+SVN

Tags: svn, redmine, scrum, trac, redmine-plugins

I'm trying to setup an agile system (SCRUM) for our small team. I know that I can use the following two options:

1- Agilo + Trac + SVN

2- Redmine + RedmineBacklogs + SVN

Which one is better? Is there any other free setup?

Comment: All local or do you have remote team members?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the best is also the cheapest.  Master this then pick tools to that will get in the way.

Note Cards + Big Wall + Markers + [Any SCC]

Comment: What does SCC stand for?

Comment: Synonymous with VCS, SCM.  Source Control.  Not sure the full acronym.  Source Code Control maybe.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the [ChiliProject](http://www.chiliproject.org) fork of Redmine. The code is currently almost the same but the long-term support is going to be with ChiliProject.

Comment: I can't agree. Upstream Redmine has been very actively developed recently. If by "support" you mean paid support, that's another issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used any of the SCRUM methodologies but for the project management I would favour Redmine over Trac.

Redmine handles multiple projects and sub projects far nicer than Trac. It's also a lot easier to set up work flows and specific roles.

There also seems to be more momentum behind Redmine with frequent updates and a reasonable pool of plugins. Although that said be aware that there is a fork of Redmine called ChiliProject, [https://www.chiliproject.org/](http://www.chiliproject.org/)  set up to "resolve management bottlenecks".